# Creating unit tests for buggy legacy code

Tags: unit-testing

We're creating unit tests for some legacy code, and in doing so we found a bug in one of our classes. It might be a while before we fix the bug. Do we

- create a unit test which demonstrates the bug and fails,
- create a unit test which reflects the current, buggy behavior and passes, or
- wait until we fix the bug to create the unit test?

Creating a unit test which passes seems funky. If we create a failing test now we'll have that hanging over us until we fix the bug, which seems ugly.

Comment: It maybe ugly but that's the whole purpose of testing results - to remind us something needs to be fixed. So yeah, option 1.

Comment: if you use GitHub, you can open an issue and add a bug tag

Comment: This seems too broad, but definitely make a test that fails. The point of unit tests is to test _units_. [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), as opposed to [DDD](http://agilemindtricks.blogspot.com/2008/01/debugger-driven-development.html), will lead to faster bug fixes, less wasted time, and more robust software.

Comment: Besides, if you write the tests now and don't fix it, when you come back you'll have documentation of cases when it fails. That's absolute gold in software development.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other testing frameworks, but for C++, the gtest framework offers an option to write tests, but disable them.

- Disabled tests are compiled (so they don't rot).
- Normally disabled tests are not run (and thus, never considered failed).
- The test output informs you about disabled tests that were not run.
- You can instruct the test executable on the command line to run the disabled tests nevertheless.

Since I am also in strong favor of option 1, the possibility to disable tests in a sensible way can help you to find a solution that works in your environment.